# What pointcut method pattern to use for interface with method that returns Collection<String>

Tags: java, aspectj

A have a simple interface:

```
package org.example.application;
import java.util.Collection;

public interface Test {
    public Collection<String> findAll();
}
```

I want to create an advice for this method when around:

```
package org.example.aspect;
import java.util.Collection;

public aspect TestAspect {
    Collection<String> around() : 
        call(Collection<String> org.example.application.Test.findAll()) {
        return proceed();
    }
}
```

I Keep getting

> advice defined in
>   org.example.aspect.TestAspect has not
>   been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days i can answer my own question:

The WARNING "advice defined in org.example.aspect.TestAspect has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]" is given when there is no call to the mothod findAll().

if you create a class that implements the interface test and has a main method that calls findAll(), the warning will vanish.

```
public class TestImpl implements Test {

    @override
    public Collection<String> findAll() {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new TestImpl();
        test.findAll();
    }
}
```